# Configure xterm to use ctrl+shift+c/ctrl+shift+v for copy/paste?

Tags: performance, gnome-terminal, xterm, gnome-terminator

I was using terminator for my terminal emulator, but I'm seeing huge performance issues with it. ie, launching a new terminal session takes 20-30 seconds on my netbook. gnome-terminal is better, but still takes 10-15 seconds to launch.

xterm however takes only a second or two. I'm fine using it, but I absolutely loathe the way it handles copy/paste.

How do I configure xterm to *not* copy something when highlighted via mouse (since I use a clipboard manager and I don't want my recently used entries to get nuked every time I select something) and use shift+ctrl+c/shift+ctrl+v for copy/paste?

OS is Debian 8, window manager is fluxbox.

Thanks!

Comment: xterm decides what to do based on the `translations` resource, which by default allows a choice between copying to the primary selection or to the clipboard.  What *should* it do when you highlight something, if not copying a selection?

Comment: When you are starting next `terminator` you can hit `ctrl+shift+i` which will spawn new window within the same process. That should take at most one second, even on old netbooks. You may also consider to start new tab (instead of new window) with `ctrl+shift+t`. Splitting terminal is yet another option.

Comment: Would you accept an answer that involves switching to another fast terminal emulator, like `st`?

Answer (score 16):

I was able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for Copy-and-Paste with XTerm by adding

```
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \
    Shift Ctrl <Key> C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Shift Ctrl <Key> V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

to my `~/.Xresources` and reloading it with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.

Documentation of this feature can be found in [*xterm(1)*, “Custom Key Bindings”](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Custom-Key-Bindings).

Comment: The xterm [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Custom-Key-Bindings) shows a more complete version of this one.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you (but really, mostly thank you for xterm), I added your link to the documentation to the answer. I hope finefoot doesn't mind.

Comment: How to do it with XTerm installed on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

It does not copy on selection. Well not really, in the same way that nothing is copied with ctrl-c, or right click copy. This is a terrible metaphor, that is used on Microsoft's windows: You right click a file on a USB storage, select copy, eject device, put it in a giffy bag, and hand it the DHL. Then click paste, only to realise that it has not made a copy. The traditional X11 way is to paste previous selection, there is no copy. I miss this working properly, many modern applications use the broken MS ctrl-c, ctrl-v model.

To solve your problem, configure the clipboard manager to ignore selection.